# reloading a page after every 10 sec in rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a rails 3.1rc4 app and i would like to update a div in my index.html.erb file after every 10sec. I dont no if this can be done via jquery? there use to be a update method but i dont no if it is for only prototype. any sample would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking down your question into sub-tasks, here's what you have to deal with:

1. retrieve (HTTP GET) html
2. update a div with the retrieved html
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 every 10 seconds

For 1, check out jquery's [.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

`Description: Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.`

For 2, check out jquery's [.html](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.html/)

```
Get the HTML contents ... or set the HTML contents of every matched element.
```

For 3, check out the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

```
Summary
Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time 
delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.
```

Final solution,

HTML  Code:

```
<div id="divToChange"></div>
```

Javascript code

```
  function update()
  { 
     $.get('/', function(data) 
     {
         $('#divToChange').html(data);
     });
  }
$(document).ready(function($){
  window.setInterval('update()', 10*1000);
});
```

Comment: pls can you tel me if your syntax is correct. and i dont think setInterval is the best approach due to server work load what of setTimeout

Comment: i tried it out and it works but it is creating another template with the general application layout inside the div i want to reload.

Comment: i tried but this time it did not work. my url is root_url which has the controller of home, maybe i dont no how to fit it in.

Comment: i have to leave it the way it is $.get("/") cos that is the url i am using a have to find a way to render a seperate layout for xhr requests

Comment: You can use either `request.xhr?` in your controller, or check the format, and use the correct reponder (js or html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming  you're familiar with javascript and possibly AJAX (if you need it).

This piece of javascript uses the native setInterval function, which calls the updateDiv function every 10 seconds.

```
var timer = setInterval(updateDiv, 10000);

function updateDiv() {
  // do update
}
```

Edit: A complete example without jQuery;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">         
      var index = 1;

      function updateDiv() {
        document.getElementById("updateMe").innerHTML = index++ + " " + new Date();
      }

      var timer = setInterval(updateDiv, 10000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="updateMe" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ple i need the part you commented out cos i am not that good with javascripts i only no how to use plugins

Comment: it works but just use a div id instead of the time. I tried mine to reload the items in a a div but did not work.