# How to reload offsite image sources every 30 seconds with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have some images from another source that need to refresh from their offsite source every 30 seconds.  I would like to use JavaScript to accomplish this so as to avoid an entire page reload.

Presently I've attempted something similar to this question: "[reloading a page after every 10 sec in rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325255/reloading-a-page-after-every-10-sec-in-rails-3-1)"

(*This is a Rails application, but I probably don't need a Rails specific answer in this case*.)

Notwithstanding, I am ending up with no appreciable result when I add a div around the link + image nor when I add a div to the image itself.  I have attempted both solutions in this example by creating a element-reload.js.

The first solution that's marked as the answer simply reloads the page with nearly all of the page elements absent.  The second solution makes the image that I'm trying to refresh actually disappear upon first refresh when I surround the link + image with a div, but when I place the id upon which it's acting on the actual image tag, it yields nothing.

I'm sure I'm missing something rather simple since JS is not a strong suit for me at the moment.

Finally, I do have a number of sources to refresh and would like to see an example of performing this for a class vs an id if possible, but having more granular control over each one may be best in the end for varied times for the refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're up for [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), this can be done quite easily:

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('img').each(function() {
      $this = $(this);

      $this.attr('src', $this.getAttribute('src') + '?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime());
      console.log($this.prop('src'));
    });
  }, 30 * 1000);
});
```

In order to prevent browser caching, you have to fool the browser and load the image with a `GET` request variable `timestamp`. It doesn't matter what the parameter is, but the image will load brand-new and not from cache because the URL changes.

---

jQuery is famous for its use of CSS-like selectors.

Replace `$('img')` with one of these:

```
$('img.yourClassName'); // Class
$('#your_id, #another_id, ...'); // ID(s). Omit the comma for a single id
$('img[id^="common_base_id"]'); // Selects all images with an id that starts with "common_base_id".
```

There's also the `:not()` selector, which can filter your results:

```
$('img.yourClassName:not(.do-not-reload)');
$('img.yourClassName:not([src="img/spinner-skip.gif"])');
```

Comment: Alright, seems good.  Effectively you're reloading all img src's in a page with this snippet it appears.  Let's say I want to reload all img src's with a class of updateAtInterval?  And then likewise, what if I decided to use an id instead of class?  Effectively could you give those two other examples as well?

Comment: Also, interestingly, I'm experimenting with the code that you gave me and whilst I see the server dishing out the requests for the images each time, I am not seeing them actually refresh in browser.  They are getting more timestamps appended to them each refresh, such as this: http://pastebin.com/vHZjeTdB

Comment: And can we put a document.write() in there for getting some output to the js console to verify we're stepping through properly?  I'm not refreshing images from my local server so I can't be sure that it's doing anything when it's hitting only the img.myRefreshClass that's yanking in from the remote.

Comment: kk, will check that.  in the interim your last edit is now not even pulling up images from the server oddly enough, now getting "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$this.getAttribute('src')')"  Hmm.

Comment: Alright, perfect!  After your last edit of changing .getAttribute to .data, it appears to be a go.  I'm seeing in the console the refresh of the img src's. I realized that there's one last div that needs a refresh and this generates a Highcharts graph.  It has an embedded script right above the div that generates it: http://pastebin.com/bEwkX8Fk -- can what you did be extended to this or is this best asked as a new question?

Comment: Highcharts graphs aren't images. Ask a new question, as the two are unrelated.

Comment: could you please add in an exception clause to this?  For example, I've added lazy image loading to the mix and it's now reloading the spinner.gif that loads every x seconds as well.  I would like to reload iff the file name doesn't match a defined option or value set in the script.

Comment: Wrap the inside code in an `if()` clause. You need to know what matches, though, so a better description would be helpful.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry, thought I was clear enough, if an image name == "spinner-skip.gif" then skip this image.  However, to be more clear, I'm using the following: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload -- This has you change src to a tmp image such as "spinner-skip.gif" and then the real image is placed on a "data-original" attribute with a second class of "lazy."  So now I have a construct like: `<img class="reloadMinutely lazy" src="img/spinner-skip.gif" data-original="img/example.jpg"  width="640" heigh="480">`

Comment: Ideally, I would add a `no-lazy-load` class to it or some other way to distinguish it easily (in case you have more images). I'll update my code.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I have to use the :not image src match due to the constraints of the classes in place. Superbly excellent information.